# Maximum Eigenvalue of the Discrete Laplace Operator (Image Processing)

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, image-processing, tridiagonal-matrices

Given the derivative operator in image processing

$$ A = \begin{bmatrix}
1 & -1 & 0 & 0 & \ldots & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 & -1 & 0 & \ldots & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 & -1 & 0 & \ldots & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & -1 & 0 & \ldots & 0 \\ 
 &  &  & \vdots &  &  &  & 
\end{bmatrix} $$

The Laplacian ([Discrete Laplace Operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_Laplace_operator)) would be given by

$$ A {A}^{T} $$

I read its maximum eigenvalue is bounded by $ 4 $.
How can it be shown?

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo, Yes it does. I will fix it in a second.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The form of $ A {A}^{T} $ is given by

$$ B = A {A}^{T} = \begin{bmatrix}
2 & -1 & 0 & \ldots & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
-1 & 2 & -1 & 0 & \ldots & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & -1 & 2 & -1 & 0 & \ldots & 0 \\ 
 &  &  & \vdots &  &  & 
\end{bmatrix} $$

Using [Gershgorin Disc Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gershgorin_circle_theorem) the discs are given by $ {R}_{ii} = \sum_{j \neq = i} \left| {b}_{ij} \right| \leq 2 $ and $ {b}_{ii} = 2 $ hence $ \forall i \; {\lambda}_{i} \leq 4 $

Answer (score 2):

$\mathrm A$ is an $(n-1) \times n$ incidence matrix. $\mathrm A \mathrm A^T$ is a **Toeplitz** and **tridiagonal** $(n-1) \times (n-1)$ symmetric matrix with $2$'s on its main diagonal and $-1$'s in the subdiagonal and superdiagonal. Hence, the $n-1$ real eigenvalues of $\mathrm A \mathrm A^T$ are given by [0]

$$\lambda_k (\mathrm A \mathrm A^T) = 2 + 2 \cos \left(\frac{k \pi}{n}\right)$$

for $k \in \{1,2,\dots,n-1\}$. Thus,

$$0 < 2 - 2 \cos \left(\frac{\pi}{n}\right) \leq \lambda_k (\mathrm A \mathrm A^T) \leq 2 + 2 \cos \left(\frac{\pi}{n}\right) < 4$$

---

[0] Silvia Noschese, Lionello Pasquini, and Lothar Reichel, [Tridiagonal Toeplitz Matrices: Properties and Novel Applications](http://www.math.kent.edu/~reichel/publications/toep3.pdf), 2006.

Comment: @Drazick Page 3 of http://www.math.kent.edu/~reichel/publications/toep3.pdf

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/nLFxk.png

Answer (score 1):

**Hint.** Simply calculate $AA^T$ explicitly and apply [Gershgorin disc theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gershgorin_circle_theorem).

Comment: I will use it and write the answer. Thank You!